# How to unit test function in React App with JEST

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Hi I am quite new in testing in JEST that why I want to ask you about some support. 

I`m trying to test function from App.js component in my App.test.js
but I recive a error:
**TypeError: _App.default.avg is not a function.**

Here is my **App.js** component

```
class App extends React.Component {

 state={ }

 avg = (elements) => {   
 let sum=0;    
 for(let i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
     sum += elements[i].main.temp;
 }
 return (sum/elements.length).toFixed(2);
 }

  render() {
    return(
      <BrowserRouter>
          <AppContext.Provider value={contextElements}>
              <div className="App container">             
                <Route path="/" component={SettingsBar}/>               
                <Route path="/settings" component={SettingsView}/>               
                <Route exact path="/" component={RootView}/>
                <Route  path="/itemview" component={ItemView}/>
              </div>
          </AppContext.Provider>     
      </BrowserRouter>

    )  
  }
}
export default App;
```

And **App.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

describe('avg', () => {

     it('should return 3 for given array [1,2,3,4,5]', () => {
         expect(App.avg([1,2,3,4,5])).toBe(3);
     });

});
```

What I`m doing wrong?

Comment: I'd say to remove the function from the app and put it in another module, file or class, that can be tested in an isolated environment. Otherwise, use [shallow mounting from something like Enzyme](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html) to have an instance of your app.

Comment: I really have to second this comment - React is self-defined as `A JavaScript library for building user interfaces` - so you really shouldn't use a React Component to house utility functions such as this unless it directly impacts what this Component renders. In that case, you should be testing what the component renders when given certain conditions, and pay no mind to that function. You should be free to refactor a component however you want and so long as it renders the same DOM as before, you shouldn't have to change your test. Doing this would force you to update tests constantly

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will try to rebuild my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try making an instance of your App.js class.

So after import you could try something like

const myApp = new App();

Then, in your expect, call myApp.avg(arguments).

Comment: That is working fine. Thanks a lot! You save my evening :)